# Copy a range of cells to script

Tags: google-sheets, copy

I would like to be able to copy the range of cells B3: B64, which could be scalable in number of lines.
When I use the script, it marks me "Undefined".
Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance to those who will help me.

Cordially.

Here is the link of my file [test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rCHzbGXxWwa_NqLa4SXPKlFrBzf6mpM3wTxjE1cO8E8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Hi,, welcome to stack overflow!
Please write your questions/answer only in english language ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this much simpler. No new array needs to be created. Try:

```
 function copier() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
   var lr=s.getLastRow() //get last row with data
   var liste = s.getRange(3,2,lr-2,1).getValues(); //get values row 3, column B (2), last row minus 2 header rows, 1 column
   s.getRange(3, 6, lr-2, 1).setValues(liste).setBackground("#97ebff") // set values and background color in column F
}   
function effacer() {
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = classeur.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('f3:f').clearContent().clearFormat();
}
```